# A word or phrase for someone who is dull and unaware of it

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Is there a good word or phrase for to describe someone is generally dull, but believes themselves to be exciting and is unaware that talking to them is laborious?

Comment: What do you mean by *awesome*?

Comment: Dunno about the *believes themselves to be exciting* bit, but ***bovine*** ([oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bovine): *sluggish or stupid*, [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bovine): *having qualities (as placidity or dullness) characteristic of oxen or cows*) works for me for the rest of it. There's a related question: [*What is the opposite of “interesting” in “This person is interesting”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/)

Comment: The cynical answer would be 'politician'.

Comment: I am not sure that anyone who's dull is aware of it. Otherwise they wouldn't be dull in the first place, right.

Comment: The term "ignorant" comes to mind.

Comment: thanks all, nothing is quite resonating yet but lets see if more suggestions arrive.

Comment: Kind of a variation on [anosognosic](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/06/20/the-anosognosics-dilemma-1/?_r=0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Dull and unaware of it* sounds like a '**drain**'.

As opposed to a **'radiator'**, someone who lights up a room and stimulates.

Drains suck the life out of a conversation or situation and make you desperate simply to be away from them.  Radiators are able to make a disaster bearable and even fun!

Answer (score 4):

*[Self-absorbed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-absorbed)*:

> adjective
>
> only caring about and interested in yourself

An interesting person can integrate their own desires, interests, and experiences with the desires, interests and experiences of others.

Answer (score 2):

Words like ***Simpleton*** or *Ignoramus* may be used.
And the phrase '***a bookful blockhead***' may be used.